# Top nav bar affix

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, affix

This is driving me nuts :(

I have **3 issues** with my code.

1.The top nav-bar is not responding with affix plug-in.The page scrolls but does not gets affixed to the top.Similar is the case with vertical affix too.I have a image in the right of the page which too does not respond with data-affix attribute.

2.The container placed below the nav-bar gets overlayed by the nav-bar.But when i change the margin-top attribute it is fine.Can it be fixed without the margin-top attribute?

3.I have placed 2 footers in the bottom of the page,in which the 2nd footer's margin gets overlapped by the content in it.This works fine if i change the margin attribute.How to fix this without changing the margin attribute?

Any help is welcome :)

P.S:I have commented in the code where there is an issue.I have searched stackoverflow too but didn't find the solution which suits me.

```css
.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 300;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #595959;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav>li>a {
  line-height: 18px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .block {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.social-fb:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  color: #3b5998;
}

.social-twitter:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  color: #55ACEE;
}

.social-google:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  color: #dd4b39;
}

.social-mail:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  color: #dd4b39;
}

.fa {
  transition: transform 0.35s ease-out;
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Welcome page</title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/194c7d5d79.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <img src="https://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2F2%2F2f%2FGoogle_2015_logo.svg%2F1200px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FList_of_Google_products&docid=vo9Ela-UL0h7xM&tbnid=pSYvYJg-2jDJSM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjZ6oXfx-LUAhVLTrwKHVV8BgUQMwhWKAIwAg..i&w=1200&h=406&bih=673&biw=1301&q=google&ved=0ahUKEwjZ6oXfx-LUAhVLTrwKHVV8BgUQMwhWKAIwAg&iact=mrc&uact=8"
      alt="" height="50px" width: "75px">
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197" role="navigation" style="height:50px;"><!--This nav bar -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="font-size:18px;letter-spacing:5px;">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i>HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="font-size:18px;">
        <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-out"></i> LOGOUT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>




  <div class="container-fluid text-center" style="margin-top:100px;">
    <div class="row content">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 sidenav" style="background-color:#f2f2f2;height:100%;">
        <p><a href="https://www.google.com">GOOGLE</a></p>
        <p><a href="https://www.gmail.com">GMAIL</a></p>
        <p><a href="https://wwww.facebook.com">FACEBOOK</a></p>
        <p><a href="https://www.whatsapp.com">WHATSAPP</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 text-left">
        <h3>Welcome
          
        </h3>
        <p>
          <h2>What is Bootstrap</h2>
          Bootstrap is an open-source Javascript framework developed by the team at Twitter. It is a combination of HTML, CSS, and Javascript code designed to help build user interface components. Bootstrap was also programmed to support both HTML5 and CSS3. Also
          it is called Front-end-framework. Bootstrap is a free collection of tools for creating a websites and web applications. It contains HTML and CSS-based design templates for typography, forms, buttons, navigation and other interface components,
          as well as optional JavaScript extensions. Some Reasons for programmers preferred Bootstrap Framework Easy to get started Great grid system Base styling for most HTML elements(Typography,Code,Tables,Forms,Buttons,Images,Icons) Extensive list
          of components Bundled Javascript plugins Bootstrap is an open-source Javascript framework developed by the team at Twitter. It is a combination of HTML, CSS, and Javascript code designed to help build user interface components. Bootstrap was
          also programmed to support both HTML5 and CSS3. Also it is called Front-end-framework. Bootstrap is a free collection of tools for creating a websites and web applications. It contains HTML and CSS-based design templates for typography, forms,
          buttons, navigation and other interface components, as well as optional JavaScript extensions. Some Reasons for programmers preferred Bootstrap Framework Easy to get started Great grid system Base styling for most HTML elements(Typography,Code,Tables,Forms,Buttons,Images,Icons)
          Extensive list of components Bundled Javascript plugins Bootstrap is an open-source Javascript framework developed by the team at Twitter. It is a combination of HTML, CSS, and Javascript code designed to help build user interface components.
          Bootstrap was also programmed to support both HTML5 and CSS3. Also it is called Front-end-framework. Bootstrap is a free collection of tools for creating a websites and web applications. It contains HTML and CSS-based design templates for typography,
          forms, buttons, navigation and other interface components, as well as optional JavaScript extensions. Some Reasons for programmers preferred Bootstrap Framework Easy to get started Great grid system Base styling for most HTML elements(Typography,Code,Tables,Forms,Buttons,Images,Icons)
          Extensive list of components Bundled Javascript plugins
        </p>
        <p>
          Bootstrap is an open-source Javascript framework developed by the team at Twitter. It is a combination of HTML, CSS, and Javascript code designed to help build user interface components. Bootstrap was also programmed to support both HTML5 and CSS3. Also
          it is called Front-end-framework. Bootstrap is a free collection of tools for creating a websites and web applications. It contains HTML and CSS-based design templates for typography, forms, buttons, navigation and other interface components,
          as well as optional JavaScript extensions. Some Reasons for programmers preferred Bootstrap Framework Easy to get started Great grid system Base styling for most HTML elements(Typography,Code,Tables,Forms,Buttons,Images,Icons) Extensive list
          of components Bundled Javascript plugins Bootstrap is an open-source Javascript framework developed by the team at Twitter. It is a combination of HTML, CSS, and Javascript code designed to help build user interface components. Bootstrap was
          also programmed to support both HTML5 and CSS3. Also it is called Front-end-framework. Bootstrap is a free collection of tools for creating a websites and web applications. It contains HTML and CSS-based design templates for typography, forms,
          buttons, navigation and other interface components, as well as optional JavaScript extensions. Some Reasons for programmers preferred Bootstrap Framework Easy to get started Great grid system Base styling for most HTML elements(Typography,Code,Tables,Forms,Buttons,Images,Icons)
          Extensive list of components Bundled Javascript plugins Bootstrap is an open-source Javascript framework developed by the team at Twitter. It is a combination of HTML, CSS, and Javascript code designed to help build user interface components.
          Bootstrap was also programmed to support both HTML5 and CSS3. Also it is called Front-end-framework. Bootstrap is a free collection of tools for creating a websites and web applications. It contains HTML and CSS-based design templates for typography,
          forms, buttons, navigation and other interface components, as well as optional JavaScript extensions. Some Reasons for programmers preferred Bootstrap Framework Easy to get started Great grid system Base styling for most HTML elements(Typography,Code,Tables,Forms,Buttons,Images,Icons)
          Extensive list of components Bundled Javascript plugins
        </p>
        <p>
          Bootstrap is an open-source Javascript framework developed by the team at Twitter. It is a combination of HTML, CSS, and Javascript code designed to help build user interface components. Bootstrap was also programmed to support both HTML5 and CSS3. Also
          it is called Front-end-framework. Bootstrap is a free collection of tools for creating a websites and web applications. It contains HTML and CSS-based design templates for typography, forms, buttons, navigation and other interface components,
          as well as optional JavaScript extensions. Some Reasons for programmers preferred Bootstrap Framework Easy to get started Great grid system Base styling for most HTML elements(Typography,Code,Tables,Forms,Buttons,Images,Icons) Extensive list
          of components Bundled Javascript plugins Bootstrap is an open-source Javascript framework developed by the team at Twitter. It is a combination of HTML, CSS, and Javascript code designed to help build user interface components. Bootstrap was
          also programmed to support both HTML5 and CSS3. Also it is called Front-end-framework. Bootstrap is a free collection of tools for creating a websites and web applications. It contains HTML and CSS-based design templates for typography, forms,
          buttons, navigation and other interface components, as well as optional JavaScript extensions. Some Reasons for programmers preferred Bootstrap Framework Easy to get started Great grid system Base styling for most HTML elements(Typography,Code,Tables,Forms,Buttons,Images,Icons)
          Extensive list of components Bundled Javascript plugins Bootstrap is an open-source Javascript framework developed by the team at Twitter. It is a combination of HTML, CSS, and Javascript code designed to help build user interface components.
          Bootstrap was also programmed to support both HTML5 and CSS3. Also it is called Front-end-framework. Bootstrap is a free collection of tools for creating a websites and web applications. It contains HTML and CSS-based design templates for typography,
          forms, buttons, navigation and other interface components, as well as optional JavaScript extensions. Some Reasons for programmers preferred Bootstrap Framework Easy to get started Great grid system Base styling for most HTML elements(Typography,Code,Tables,Forms,Buttons,Images,Icons)
          Extensive list of components Bundled Javascript plugins
        </p>

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 sidenav">
        <img src="./images/i.jpg" alt="" height="500" width="100%">
        <!-- this image not working with affix  insert image of your choice and check it-->


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-bottom" style="height:200px;background-color:whitesmoke;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
          <center>
            <h2>Contact us</h2>
            <address>
                            Coimbatore <br>
                            India <br>
                        </address>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x social-fb"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x social-twitter"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="https://plus.google.com"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-3x social-google"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-3x social-mail"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;

          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="position:fixed-bottom;margin-top:30px;"><!-- This 2nd footer -->
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
          <center>
            <h4>Powered by GOOGLE</h4>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please someone help me out in this problem

Comment: Pasting your code into a Bootply and affix seems to be operating as expected: https://www.bootply.com/GGMa4nGOTL   Did you remember to include Bootstrap's JS?

Comment: Yes i have included bootstrap JS too

Answer (score 0):

To fix the navbar to the top of the screen (Your question is very unclear so I'm guessing this is what you are asking) you don't need a plugin... Bootstrap can do this by defualt.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

See this Codepen for an example:

https://codepen.io/GuruTom/pen/MoQGXX

Comment: This nav-bar is fixed to the top.Sorry to say that this is not my required answer.I have a image above the nav bar and on scrolling the nav-bar should  get affixed to the top :)

Comment: wait so a full-screen image and as you scroll down, the navbar is collected and fixed to the top? I have this on my personal laptop at home I will update my answer when I'm home from work